What was "Mac SLM" or "ASLM"?
While looking through a very old codebase, I found some preprocessor defines and comments referring to something called "Mac SLM" or "ASLM".  From the context, it appears to have been an Apple-related platform, compiler, or development environment, and required the re-implementation of some functions from the C standard library.
Google searches are turning up nothing relevant, which isn't surprising for something that appears to have vanished at least 30 years ago.

Mind to add some basic information, maybe starting with the language used, when written, for what environment and alike?

@Raffzahn, other than the date (originally written in the early 1990s and updated since), it's hard to say, not least because of confusion on the part of the original programmer.  Some of the comments and naming suggest difficulty telling the difference between a compiler, an operating system, and a computer architecture.

ASLM sounds quite like Apple Shared Library Manager, the original way shared libraries were handled on classic MacOS (68k & PPC). Usually created using MPW.

ASLM was the original way to handle shared code on 68k Macs. It was ported to PPC as well, though native PPC applications had their own way, using the Code Fragment Manager (CFM) - which in turn was also backported to 68k to allow creation of backward compatible applications :))

Having done a lot of Mac programming back in the day, I believe this is the correct answer.  There certainly was an Apple Shared Library Manager.  However, I developed with THINK C and Codewarrior, which made no use of ASLM macros, so it must indeed be something specific to those using MPW as their development environment.

@DrSheldon I remember the network (system 7.*?) being a shared library, so before doing any network call one had to use ASLM to open it (and close afterwards).
